# How to configure "HTTP_request_configuration" in Anypoint Studio?

Tags: configuration, mule, httprequest, anypoint-studio

I am using **Anypoint** 6.2.3 and I am trying to call an api **baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler** for that, my project flow is

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="9000" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="baconipsum.com"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="api" port="8081"/>
<flow name="test2Flow1" >
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" >
      <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="type" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.type]"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="sentences" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.sentences]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
  <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:/Users/arpit_jain2/Desktop/Response" outputPattern="res.json" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

and the HTTP_Request_Configuration is

[HTTP_Request_Configuration](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/_images/http+global+element+baconipsum.png)

In the documentation of MuleSoft, port number is not assigned and it is working fine but when I implement the same configuration I get the error.

***Value for port must be provided***

Does anyone know what should be the port and why I am getting null payload error.

[Error while calling the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QdF7.png)
Am I missing something in the Anypoint configuration or in the HTTP_Request_Configuraion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default port for http is 80. So set port="80"

You have set to 8081 and http://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler is listening on 80(default) not 8081

Comment: I had a similar issue and changing the port to 80 did the trick for me (or 443 for https).

Answer (score 0):

Please set port = 80 in your HTTP Request Config.

Answer (score -1):

Here two changes that you can try.
1.Change your *basePath="api"* to *basePath="/api"* and try it. And
2.Try without adding any port as you mentioned **baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler**.

If still you are facing the issue then post the complete error details that you are getting.